# update flask project from python2 to python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

my small flask project is run normally on python2, but when i upgrade to python3, meet some problems:

first, my files' tree:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── app1
│   │   ├── app1.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── templates
│        ├── base.html
│        └── index.html
├── config.py
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── run.py
├── shell.py
└── test.db
```

run.py:

```
from app import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

app/__init__.py:

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, render_template
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

from app1.app1 import mod as app1
```

when i use python2 to run:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
```

no problems, but on python3:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 4, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/home/chenhj/flask/multiapp/app/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from app1.app1 import mod as app1
ImportError: No module named 'app1'
```

anyone knows why? rookie to python3 and need help :)

Comment: my python3 version is python3.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using *implicit relative* imports (the Python 2 model); you need to use absolute references or explicit relative imports:

```
from .app1.app1 import mod as app1
```

where the leading `.` signals that the rest is relative to the current package, or

```
from app.app1.app1 import mod as app1
```

See [PEP 328 - *Imports: Multi-Line and Absolute/Relative*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/).

You probably will have other issues however. Porting is not that trivial, read up on the issues in the [Porting to Python 3 book](http://python3porting.com/). This issue is  [a common migration problem](http://python3porting.com/problems.html).